# Two inner joins cause slow execution

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-performance

I have two inner joins in my SQL query:

```sql
SELECT `M`.`msg_id`,
       `U`.`username`,
       `U`.`seo_username`
FROM `newdb2`.`users` AS `U`
INNER JOIN (SELECT subscriber_to_id
            FROM subscriptions
            WHERE subscriber_id = 434) AS subscriber 
  ON id = subscriber_to_id
INNER JOIN `newdb2`.`messages` AS `M` 
  ON (`M`.`uid_fk` = `U`.`id`)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

When I execute this query I see that is really slow.
How can I modify thiş query to make it faster?

Comment: How many rows has thoose tables?

Comment: list the indexes you have.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fixes for things like this are adding indexes which allows your database server to quickly look up columns you are searching on. [For more info on how to add indexes to columns, see the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).

In this query, those columns are:

- subscriptions.subscriber_id
- subscriptions.subscriber_to_id
- users.id
- messages.uid_fk

The `ORDER BY id` should be OK as I assume your `id` column has a primary key index on it already, but ordering queries will slow it down too.

Subselect queries will also slow the query down. In this particular query, I can't see the alias `subscriber` (containing the results of your subquery, which is `inner join`ed on) used anywhere, so remove that join completely.